# Fill in sequence numbers in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence, fill

I have a table that includes two columns, these columns have ranges i.e

```
 Batch  from _serial_no to_serial_no
 a  1   5
 b  2   7
```

I want to create another column to fill in the gaps for a abd b separately 
Something like this

```
 Batch  from _serial_no to_serial_no    seq_number
 a  1   5   1
 a  1   5   2
 a  1   5   3
 a  1   5   4
 a  1   5   5
 b  2   7   2
 b  2   7   3
 b  2   7   4
 b  2   7   5
 b  2   7   6
 b  2   7   7
```

Is there an sql I could use?

I tried something like this but it didn't work

```
 select * 
 from ( 
      select a.*,rownum n   
      from my_table a connect by level <= TO_SERIAL_NO
 )  
 where n >= FROM_SERIAL_NO;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another option:

```
SQL> with test (batch, from_serial_no, to_serial_no) as
  2    (select 'a', 1, 5 from dual union
  3     select 'b', 2, 7 from dual
  4    )
  5  select
  6    batch,
  7    from_serial_no,
  8    to_serial_no,
  9    froM_serial_no + column_value - 1 seq_number
 10  from test,
 11       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                           connect by level <= to_serial_no - from_serial_no + 1
 13                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 14  order by batch, seq_number;

B FROM_SERIAL_NO TO_SERIAL_NO SEQ_NUMBER
- -------------- ------------ ----------
a              1            5          1
a              1            5          2
a              1            5          3
a              1            5          4
a              1            5          5
b              2            7          2
b              2            7          3
b              2            7          4
b              2            7          5
b              2            7          6
b              2            7          7

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: @ast the best way to say thank you on SO is to mark answer as a correct ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
SQL> with
  2    data as (select 'a' batch, 1 from_serial_number, 5 to_serial_number from dual
  3             union all
  4             select 'b' batch, 2 from_serial_number, 7 to_serial_number from dual),
  5    seq as (select rownum n# from dual connect by level <= (select max(to_serial_number) from data))
  6  select
  7    data.*,
  8    seq.n#
  9  from
 10    data,
 11    seq
 12  where
 13    seq.n# between data.from_serial_number and data.to_serial_number
 14  order by
 15    1, 2, 4;

BATCH FROM_SERIAL_NUMBER TO_SERIAL_NUMBER         N#
----- ------------------ ---------------- ----------
a                      1                5          1
a                      1                5          2
a                      1                5          3
a                      1                5          4
a                      1                5          5
b                      2                7          2
b                      2                7          3
b                      2                7          4
b                      2                7          5
b                      2                7          6
b                      2                7          7

11 rows selected
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! That could work really well!! However unfortunately the table that i have doesn't have just a and b in the batch column, it has someting like 1000 different values so it would be difficult to union all possible values for the batch column. Plus batch values have (valid) duplicates. Do you think there is way to incoorporate that into the sql?

Comment: Yes; have a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a `join`

```
select d.*, t.seq_number
from data d
join
(
   SELECT  from_serial_no + level - 1 seq_number
   FROM    (select min(from_serial_no) from_serial_no, 
                   max(to_serial_no) to_serial_no 
            from data) t
   CONNECT BY from_serial_no + level - 1 <= to_serial_no
) t on d.from_serial_no <= t.seq_number and
       d.to_serial_no >= t.seq_number
order by d.batch, t.seq_number;
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=726419f52fad765a2257616078b5d051)